# Passing single record to Copy Activity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

How to pass record by record in a sequential manner to a Copy Activity (including stored proc) in ADF V2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by doing a lookup activity calling your sp, then do a foreach where each item is a record. Inside the foreach, you can have a copy activity where you insert only that row.

This way of working will have a ton of overhead time!! Also it will use a ton of activities making your whole money consumption on Data Factory much more expensive than it needs to be. Only apply it when its super mandatory, and warn everyone about the cost so you dont get into trouble.

Maybe if you could share a bit more on your scenario we are able to suggest a better process.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: I have to agree with Martin - is there any way you can pass the unsorted list down, eg into a table, then call a stored proc to work through it?  A better way would be to refactor your process to work in parallel?  This would take advantage of the ForEach task ability to run up to 20 tasks in parallel.

Comment: Being more specific about the scenario, I'm passing the data using user defined table type to the SP and then making updates on multiple tables fetching the data from the UDT inside the SP. Is there any way out, to pass row by row to the SP from the UDT rather than the bulk data. Please let me know if I'm still unclear about the ask.

Comment: Either refactor your process so it is not dependent on row-by-row processing OR refactor your process to ensure this row-by-row processing does not happen in Azure Data Factory (ADF).  eg pass your full dataset into a parent stored procedure, which calls off to a child procedure.  This way your ADF pipeline will only contain two tasks, a Lookup and a Stored Proc task and will not incur the massive performance and potential cost overhead induced by using the RBAR anti-pattern  in ADF, as clearly outlined by Martin.